# Get total item count from firebase recycler adapter

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

here's my code snippet-
I want to get total item count in my activity. (i.e. all the children from the databaseReference. And also I requires that the total child count changes dynamically i.e if child is added or removed.

```
firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Chat>().setQuery(databaseReference,Chat.class).build();

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chat, ChatHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions)
    {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(ChatHolder holder, int position, Chat model)
        {

            holder.txtName.setText(model.getName());

        }

        @Override
        public ChatHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chats, parent, false);
            return new ChatHolder(view);
        }



        @Override
        public void onDataChanged() {
            super.onDataChanged();

            firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, you need to use `getItemCount()` method which counts all your items from your `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: firebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount(). This is returning 0.

Comment: You need to use `getItemCount()` inside `populateViewHolder()` method. Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
 DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("yourChild");
 int childCount = 0;

        database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    childCount+=snap.getChildrenCount();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

    });
```

Comment: My firebase document is as-

Details
         Key
               Id
               Name
_________
         Key
               Id
               Name
.....................................

using the above method returning me 4 i.e. the children inside key. but i requires the value 2. (i.e. total keys in my  Detail document)..
 
And also if i print childCount inside onDataChanged only then it is giving value 4 and if i use childCount  anywhere it gives 0 ..

Comment: @Raj thanks for the comment. Infact your comment saved my day. I was using getItemCount in onBindViewHolder, but while I move it to onDataChanged it worked magically. Thanks.